# How to interpret Pauli spinors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, schroedinger-equation, spinors

Recently in my QM course we derived the Pauli equation for an electron in a magnetic field. From what I understand, since we now have a spin-dependent term in our Hamiltonian, the spatial and spin degrees of freedom of the electron are now coupled. Hence, the wavefunction should in principle be different depending on whether the electron is spin-up or down, and therefore it's useful to write our Schrodinger equation using a 2-component wavefunction, represented by a mathematical object known as a spinor:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_+ \\
\psi_- \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $\psi_+$ is the wavefunction for when the electron is sping-up, and $\psi_-$ for when it's spin-down.

While I understand the need for two different wavefunctions depending on the spin, there are still some doubts regarding the interpretation of this spinor which I'd like to clear up:

1. Can you interpret the spinor as a sum of 2 tensor direct products of vectors in the position degree of freedom space and in the spin degree of freedom space? Really what I'm asking is is the spinor equivalent to saying the state of our system is
   $$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{2}} (|\psi_+\rangle \otimes |\uparrow\rangle + |\psi_-\rangle \otimes |\downarrow\rangle).$$
   I would assume this is right as to describe both position and spin simultaneously you'd need a tensor product space of an infinite-dimensional position eigenket space and a 2-dimensional spin eigenket space, but I want to make sure this is actually what the spinor means.
2. I'm guessing that if your system is initially in a mixture of spin-up and spin-down states (as in the expression in question 1), and you measure the spin in the z-direction, the outcome of your measurement will also collapse your spatial wavefunction into either $\psi_+$ or $\psi_-$ as the position and spin degrees of freedom are coupled. But what if you start with a mixture but measure position before spin? I understand that the squared moduli of $\psi_+$ and $\psi_-$ give you the position probability distributions of the electron in its spin-up and spin-down states respectively, but what is the position probability distribution when it's still in a mixture of spin states?

If either of these doubts could be cleared up it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...a 2-component wavefunction, represented by a mathematical object known as a spinor:
> $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
> \psi_+ \\
> \psi_- \\
> \end{pmatrix}\tag{A}
> $$

> ...there are still some doubts regarding the interpretation of this spinor which I'd like to clear up:

> 1. Can you interpret the spinor as a sum of 2 tensor direct products of vectors in the position degree of freedom space and in the spin degree of freedom space? Really what I'm asking is is the spinor equivalent to saying the state of our system is
>    $$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{2}} (|\psi_+\rangle \otimes |\uparrow\rangle + |\psi_-\rangle \otimes |\downarrow\rangle).$$

I would write the direct product notation as:
$$
|\psi_+\rangle\otimes|\uparrow\rangle + 
|\psi_-\rangle\otimes|\downarrow\rangle\;,
$$
whereas you seem to have inserted a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ by hand, which is inconsistent with your Eq. (A) above.

---

If we use a notation that is consistent with your Eq. (A) above, we write:
$$
1 = \langle\psi_+|\psi_+\rangle + \langle\psi_-|\psi_-\rangle
=\int d^3r\left(|\psi_+(\vec r)|^2 + |\psi_-(\vec r)|^2\right)\;.
$$

The probability to measure spin up is:
$$
\langle\psi_+|\psi_+\rangle = \int d^3r |\psi_+(\vec r)|^2\;.
$$

And the probability to measure spin down is:
$$
\langle\psi_-|\psi_-\rangle = \int d^3r |\psi_-(\vec r)|^2\;.
$$

The above expressions for probability can be obtained from the [the usual partial measurement rules](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Quantum_Mechanics/Quantum_Mechanics_III_(Chong)/03%3A_Quantum_Entanglement/3.02%3A_Partial_Measurements).

> 2. I'm guessing that if your system is initially in a mixture of spin-up and spin-down states (as in the expression in question 1), and you measure the spin in the z-direction, the outcome of your measurement will also collapse your spatial wavefunction into either $\psi_+$ or $\psi_-$ as the position and spin degrees of freedom are coupled.

Yes, the state will collapse, but the collapsed state after the measurement must be normalized ("by hand").

For example, measuring spin-up will collapse the state to:
$$
\frac{|\psi_+\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle\psi_+|\psi_+\rangle}}
$$

> But what if you start with a mixture but measure position before spin? I understand that the squared moduli of $\psi_+$ and $\psi_-$ give you the position probability distributions of the electron in its spin-up and spin-down states respectively, but what is the position probability distribution when it's still in a mixture of spin states?

Just like we sum (or rather, integrate) over the spatial position to get the overall probability to measure some given spin, similarly, we sum over spin to get the overall probability density to measure some given position.
$$
p(\vec r) =\sum_{i=\uparrow, \downarrow} |\psi_i(\vec r)|^2
\;, 
$$
where technically $p(\vec r)$ is a probability density rather than a probability.

---

**Update** (to address additional questions in the comments):

In general, if a measurement is "projective" (which is a common kind of measurement, but not necessarily the most general), then we can use a projection operator to understand the collapse of the wavefunction after the measurement as well as the probability to measure a specific value.

Measurement of the position is a little more complicated since position is a continuous variable, and so we need to at least integrate over a small region $\delta V$ to interpret our results in terms of a probability rather than probability density.

For example, suppose we measure the position and we find the particle within $\delta V$ of $\vec r_0$. The relevant projection operator is:
$$
\hat \Pi_{\vec r_0} = \int_{\delta V}d^3r'|\vec r_0+\vec r'\rangle\langle \vec r_0 + \vec r'|\;,
$$
where $|r\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the position operator.

This projection operator's action on $\psi$ is:
$$
\hat \Pi|\psi\rangle = \int_{\delta V} d^3r' 
\left(
\psi_+(\vec r'+\vec r_0)|\vec r' + \vec r_0\rangle|\uparrow\rangle
+
\psi_-(\vec r'+\vec r_0)|\vec r' + \vec r_0\rangle|\downarrow\rangle
\right)\;.
$$

The probability to measure $\vec r_0$ within $\delta V$ is:
$$
P(\vec r_0; \delta V) = \langle \psi|\Pi^\dagger \Pi|\psi \rangle
=
\langle \psi|\Pi|\psi \rangle
$$
$$
=\int_{\delta V}d^3r' 
\left(
|\psi_+(\vec r'+\vec r_0)|^2
+
|\psi_-(\vec r'+\vec r_0)|^2
\right)\;,
$$
which is consistent with our expression for probability density above.

The state of the system after the measurement collapse is described by the normalized ket:
$$
|\chi_{\vec r_0;\delta V}\rangle = \frac{\hat \Pi|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle\psi|\hat\Pi^\dagger\hat \Pi|\psi\rangle}}
$$
$$
=\frac{\int_{\delta V}d^3r\left(
\psi_+(\vec r_0+\vec r)|\vec r_0 +\vec r\rangle|\uparrow\rangle
+
\psi_-(\vec r_0+\vec r)|\vec r_0 +\vec r\rangle|\downarrow\rangle
\right)}
{\sqrt{\int_{\delta V}d^3r
\left(|\psi_+(\vec r_0+\vec r)|^2+|\psi_-(\vec r_0+\vec r)|^2
\right)}}
$$

If we take $\delta V$ to be very small in comparison with any length scale over which $\psi_i(\vec r)$ changes, e.g., take the limit $\delta V \to 0$, we find that collapsed state becomes:
$$
|\chi_{\vec r_0;\delta V}\rangle \underbrace{\to}_{\delta V\to 0} |\vec r_0\rangle\sqrt{\delta V}\frac{\psi_+(\vec r_0)|\uparrow\rangle + \psi_-(\vec r_0)|\downarrow\rangle}{\sqrt{|\psi_+(\vec r_0)|^2+|\psi_-(\vec r_0)|^2}}\;,
$$
however, as usual, the position eigenkets are eigenkets of a continuous operator, and are non-normalizable (they are delta normalized), so they can not represent the true physical state of the system.

But the state $|\chi_{\vec r_0;\delta V}\rangle$, prior to taking the limit, can represent the state of the system after a measurement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This definitely made things clearer. Just another quick question. Clearly $|\psi_+\rangle$ and $|\psi_-\rangle$ are not initially normalized, or else we could not uphold the normalization condition $1 = \langle\psi_+|\psi_+\rangle + \langle\psi_-|\psi_-\rangle$. You mentioned that upon measuring spin, the spatial state the system collapses in is normalized. Is the normalization factor, for example $\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{\langle\psi_+|\psi_+\rangle}}$ as you mentioned, something we manually add due to physical necessity or does it mathematically arise from anywhere?

Comment: You can think of it as being "manually added." This happens because measurement is quite a different animal from the usual unitary evolution we are used to. Measurement irreversibly collapses the state and all other information about the original state is lost. The normalization factor is inserted "by hand" (in a sense) to account for this loss.

Comment: I also updated my answer to reflect my comment.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! I did also want to ask, does a position measurement when your system is still in a mixture of states collapse the system into being spin-up or spin-down the same way a spin measurement does or does it stay in a mixture?

Comment: A position measurement collapses the system to a position eigenstate. A position measurement is a projective measurement, just like a spin measurement is. I will update my answer to explain this.

Comment: Awesome, it all seems clear now! Thanks a lot for your in-depth reply, honestly really helpful

Comment: @SamueleFossati I'm glad it helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Just in terms of convention, usually, when you write it as a column vector like in the [Pauli equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_equation) the waves are already normalized:
   $$
   \sum_\pm\langle \psi_\pm|\psi_\pm\rangle=1
   $$
   so you don’t need the additional normalization:
   $$
   |\psi\rangle=|\psi_+\rangle\otimes|+\rangle+ |\psi_-\rangle\otimes|-\rangle
   $$
2. The Born rules apply. If you measure along spin along the $z$ axis

- with probability $\langle \psi_+|\psi_+\rangle$ you measure $+$,  the state collapses to (the final state is not normalized):
  $$
  \psi\to |\psi_+\rangle\otimes|+\rangle
  $$
- with probability $\langle \psi_-|\psi_-\rangle$ you measure $-$, the state collapses to:
  $$
  \psi\to |\psi_-\rangle\otimes|-\rangle
  $$
  The reasoning is the same when you measure position. With probability $(|\psi_+(x)|^2+ |\psi_-(x)|^2)dx$ you measure position between $x,x+dx$, the state collapses to:
  $$
  \psi\to \psi_+(x) |x\rangle\otimes |+\rangle+ \psi_-(x) |x\rangle\otimes  |-\rangle
  $$
  where I used the shorthand $\psi_\pm(x)=\langle x|\psi_\pm\rangle$

Hope this helps.